# How to stop broadcast mac and print only actual mac address

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, arp, pyshark

I want to print only when i got actual mac address else wait

```
import time  

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wlo2', bpf_filter='arp')

capture.sniff(timeout=3)

keys = {}

e_mac = '00.00.00.00.00.00'

for packet in capture:
    keys['ip'] = packet.arp.dst_proto_ipv4

    keys['mac'] = packet.arp.dst_hw_mac

    if keys['mac'] != e_mac:
        print(time.strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S '), keys['mac'], keys['ip'])
```

output:

```
Dec 06 12:57:08  00:00:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.40
Dec 06 12:59:53  00:00:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.40
Dec 06 13:01:46  00:00:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.195
Dec 06 13:01:55  f8:c4:f3:56:a3:70 192.168.1.1
Dec 06 13:08:24  00:00:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time  

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wlo2', bpf_filter='arp')

capture.sniff(timeout=3)

keys = {}

e_mac = '00:00:00:00:00:00' #forgot to add colon in ques

for packet in capture:
    keys['ip'] = packet.arp.dst_proto_ipv4

    keys['mac'] = packet.arp.dst_hw_mac

    if keys['mac'] != e_mac:
        print(time.strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S '), keys['mac'], keys['ip'])
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: yes it is@Timus

Comment: Okay, now I see the difference. Maybe you could reduce the answer to the part that you had to change, or at least point that part out. Otherwise the answer is hard to read.